# How to create a parent directory with multiple subdirectories which has nested subdirectories within the respective subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, directory, subdirectory, mkdir

I'm new to shell scripting. I'm trying to create a main folder called Analysis. In the **Analysis** folder I would like four sub-folders named, **PhenV1**, **PhenV2**, **HypV1**, and **HypV2**. I then want to have each of those four sub-folders have another 2 folders named **Genes** and **Variants** and in each of the **Genes** and **Variants** folders to have two more folders named **CNV** and **SNV.** The directory structure is depicted by the image below. Here is what I've attempted

```
mkdir -p Analysis/PhenV1/{Genes/{CNV,SNV},Variants/{CNV,SNV},PhenV2/{Genes/{CNV,SNV},Variants/{CNV,SNV},HypV1/{Genes/{CNV,SNV},Variants/{CNV,SNV},HypV2/{Genes/{CNV,SNV},Variants/{CNV,SNV}}
```

This code only creates the parent folder Analysis, and subdirectories, PhenV1 and {Genes''m

[image]

Comment: The tree you show does not match the command you tried: in your command you have `CNV`, `SNV`, `SN`, `CMT` and `VT` leaves while your tree has only `CNV`and `SNV`. Please edit your question.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Comment: @rob This is a question about `bash` brace expansion, not operating systems. IMHO it is perfectly on-topic. You could maybe suggest to delete useless tags but as long as the `bash`tag is present this is a `bash` programming question.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet thank you for pointing this out. The command has been edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mkdir -p Analysis/{PhenV1,Phenv2,HypV1,HypV2}/{Genes,Variants}/{CNV,SNV}
```

Creates:

```
$ tree
.
└── Analysis
    ├── HypV1
    │   ├── Genes
    │   │   ├── CNV
    │   │   └── SNV
    │   └── Variants
    │       ├── CNV
    │       └── SNV
    ├── HypV2
    │   ├── Genes
    │   │   ├── CNV
    │   │   └── SNV
    │   └── Variants
    │       ├── CNV
    │       └── SNV
    ├── PhenV1
    │   ├── Genes
    │   │   ├── CNV
    │   │   └── SNV
    │   └── Variants
    │       ├── CNV
    │       └── SNV
    └── Phenv2
        ├── Genes
        │   ├── CNV
        │   └── SNV
        └── Variants
            ├── CNV
            └── SNV

29 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: Thanks, This command works effortlessly.  It's  lot easier than trying to keep up with adding brackets

Comment: @geneteics_diva Great. If an answer works you can accept it (if you want to).

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are not properly balanced. Try:

```
Analysis/{PhenV1/{Genes/{CNV,SNV},Variants/{CNV,SNV}},PhenV2/{Genes/{CNV,SNV},Variants/{CNV,SNV}},HypV1/{Genes/{CNV,SN},Variants/{CMC,VT}},HypV2/{Genes/{CNV,SNV},Variants/{CNV,SNV}}}
```

Which can be simplified a bit:

```
Analysis/{{PhenV1,PhenV2,HypV2}/{Genes,Variants}/{CNV,SNV},HypV1/{Genes/{CNV,SN},Variants/{CMC,VT}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I figured it was a matter of unbalanced brackets once I started to do the command step-by-step. The first version of your answer works but the simplified version seems to be an issue of unbalanced brackets again. Nevertheless, I know now to be mindful of balancing my brackets . Great learning lesson for me :-)

Comment: Strange. I just tested with `printf '%s\n' Analysis/{{PhenV1,PhenV2,HypV2}/{Genes,Variants}/{CNV,SNV},HypV1/{Genes/{CNV,SN},Variants/{CMC,VT}}}` and it produces what you expect. Are you sure you correctly copy-pasted everything?